# PowerMock + Robolectric + ActiveAndroid

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, robolectric, powermock

I use ActiveAndroid library for working with the database. The automatic test crashes with an error when I create an object model.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.activeandroid.Cache.getTableInfo(Cache.java:148)
    at com.activeandroid.Model.<init>(Model.java:54)
    at handsfree.penny.mvp.model.Subject.<init>(Subject.java:18)
    at handsfree.penny.presenter.subjectlist.SubjectListPresenterTest.createSubjectsList(SubjectListPresenterTest.java:54)
    at handsfree.penny.presenter.subjectlist.SubjectListPresenterTest.setup(SubjectListPresenterTest.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

I found a solution - https://github.com/kaeawc/testable-active-android/blob/master/app/src/test/java/io/kaeawc/activeandroidapp/model/ActiveAndroidModelSpec.java

But the fact is that in addition I need `PowerMockRunner` and  `RobolectricGradleTestRunner`. The project uses the class Application (it is stored on the Component Dagger). Options from here did not help.

In the first case:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, manifest = "src/test/TestManifest.xml", sdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@PowerMockIgnore({"org.mockito.*", "org.robolectric.*", "android.*"})
@PrepareForTest({ Cache.class, TableInfo.class, Context.class, ContentResolver.class, ContentProvider.class, ContentValues.class })
@SuppressStaticInitializationFor("com.activeandroid.content.ContentProvider")
public class BaseTest {

    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    @Test
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ContentProvider.class);

        PowerMockito.when(ContentProvider.createUri(Model.class, 0l)).thenReturn(null);
        assertTrue(ContentProvider.createUri(null, null) == null);
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name android.content.ContentProvider. Reason: cannot find android.content.IContentProvider

    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:283)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:192)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:286)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:192)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at handsfree.penny.common.BaseTest.setup(BaseTest.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement$1.run(PowerMockRule.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.performMethodInvocation(WhiteboxImpl.java:1899)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:801)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:666)
    at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:401)
    at org.powermock.classloading.AbstractClassloaderExecutor.getResult(AbstractClassloaderExecutor.java:69)
    at org.powermock.classloading.AbstractClassloaderExecutor.executeWithClassLoader(AbstractClassloaderExecutor.java:59)
    at org.powermock.classloading.SingleClassloaderExecutor.execute(SingleClassloaderExecutor.java:67)
    at org.powermock.classloading.AbstractClassloaderExecutor.execute(AbstractClassloaderExecutor.java:43)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement.evaluate(PowerMockRule.java:75)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:251)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:152)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: javassist.CannotCompileException: cannot find android.content.IContentProvider
    at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:771)
    at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:734)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.AbstractMainMockTransformer.modifyMethod(AbstractMainMockTransformer.java:207)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.AbstractMainMockTransformer.allowMockingOfStaticAndFinalAndNativeMethods(AbstractMainMockTransformer.java:112)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.ClassMockTransformer.transformMockClass(ClassMockTransformer.java:56)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.AbstractMainMockTransformer.transform(AbstractMainMockTransformer.java:247)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:264)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: javassist.NotFoundException: android.content.IContentProvider
    at javassist.ClassPool.get(ClassPool.java:452)
    at javassist.bytecode.Descriptor.toCtClass(Descriptor.java:592)
    at javassist.bytecode.Descriptor.getParameterTypes(Descriptor.java:439)
    at javassist.CtBehavior.getParameterTypes(CtBehavior.java:298)
    at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:749)
    ... 66 more
```

In the second case :

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21)
@PowerMockIgnore({ "org.mockito.*", "org.robolectric.*", "android.*" })
@PrepareForTest(ContentProvider.class)
public class MyTest{


    @Test
    public void testStaticMocking() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ContentProvider.class);

        PowerMockito.when(ContentProvider.createUri(Model.class, 0l)).thenReturn(null);
        assertTrue(ContentProvider.createUri(null, null) == null);
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.powermock.api.mockito.ClassNotPreparedException: 
The class com.activeandroid.content.ContentProvider not prepared for test.
To prepare this class, add class to the '@PrepareForTest' annotation.
In case if you don't use this annotation, add the annotation on class or  method level. 


    at org.powermock.api.mockito.expectation.reporter.MockitoPowerMockReporter.classNotPrepared(MockitoPowerMockReporter.java:31)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockTypeValidatorFactory$DefaultMockTypeValidator.validate(MockTypeValidatorFactory.java:38)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.AbstractMockCreator.validateType(AbstractMockCreator.java:18)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.createMock(MockCreator.java:57)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.mock(MockCreator.java:47)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic(PowerMockito.java:71)
    at handsfree.penny.common.DeckardActivityTest.testStaticMocking(DeckardActivityTest.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:251)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:152)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner$2.call(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:148)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner$2.call(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:140)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner.withContextClassLoader(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:131)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner.run(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:140)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:121)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

For the exception "org.powermock.api.mockito.ClassNotPreparedException: "
You could try to put this annotation on top of the class declaration or test method.

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(CommPortIdentifier.class)

All the best,